# Android: Rearrange children between multiple linearLayouts

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-animation

I am working on animating few imageviews spread across different layouts in order to simulate a football formation.

For eg. this is config 1:

```
===============================


 1        2        3       4

===============================


      5        6        7

===============================


      8        9        10

===============================
```

The numbers above are imageviews inside respective horizontal LinearLayouts. I want this to switch to config 2 (which contains 5 numbers in the topmost LinearLayout and 2 in the middle layout. Lower is unchanged.)

```
===============================


 1      2      3     4     5

===============================


           6        7

===============================


      8        9        10

===============================
```

Now, so far I am able to dynamically add and delete imageViews inside the linear layouts. However the transition seems very abrupt. So I wanted to know if an animation can be used to show:

1. The upper layout elements adjusting their positions due to new arrival.
2. Number 5 moving from mid to top.
3. The mid row elements adjusting their positions so as to account for deletion.

The caveat is that since Number 5 is no longer a member of mid layout, would it be possible at all to show it transitioning.

EDIT: The above change of config was only a representative example. In reality there can be multiple formations and transition can be made from any one to any other. Also the solution must be "fluid" and not depend on hardcoded pixel values. So far, I am able to take care of the rearrangement part due to deletion or addition (without the animation of course).

Comment: share your code or workarounds

Comment: and this is not the way to do it

Comment: Okay. I will share the code in some time. (It's on a different machine). Although what would be the right way? I tried tableLayout, gridView etc too, with no tangible solution.

Comment: Add recyclerView dynamically or static if only 3 layer is there. then add or remove items in recyclerView And add itemanimation to recyclerView . you can do it in les than half an hour of time.

Comment: The layers are constant. If it works out, you may add it as an answer so I'll accept it.

Comment: And you can find libraries in android arsenal. but i will not suggest it. Dont depend on others.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem i will use translate animation.

Here is the example how to do that.

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
setContentView(relativeLayout);

final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_your_icon);
relativeLayout.addView(imageView);

final float amountToMoveRight = imageView.getX() + 100;
final float amountToMoveDown = imageView.getY() + 100;

TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(imageView.getX(), imageView.getX() + 100, imageView.getY(), imageView.getY() + 100);
anim.setDuration(2000);

anim.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
        params.topMargin += amountToMoveDown;
        params.leftMargin += amountToMoveRight;
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
});

imageView.startAnimation(anim);
```

You can get the position of each view by using `imageView.getX();` and `imageView.getY();`